# No increment in a For loop

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, increment

I have a problem which seems quite simple but something is going wrong.

I´m using a for loop and an int variable nForCount for initialisation, condition and increment.

I expect that nForCount increases with 1 after each loop. 
But it´s not even initialising to 0. In the console nForCount shows nothing. see picture.

[image]

My Code:

```
int nForCount   = 0;
int vlFilesOriginal = 100;

for (nForCount = 0; nForCount < vlFilesOriginal; nForCount++) {

    printf("AppDelegate/refreshDRPopsWrapper•987: %03i \n",nForCount);

}
```

Comment: this isn't the code, pls show us how and where you declare nForCount, vlFilesOriginal. your example code works fine...

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to declare the iteration var inside the for-loop statement.
Try this:

```
int vlFilesOriginal = 100;

for (int nForCount = 0; nForCount < vlFilesOriginal; nForCount++) {

    printf("AppDelegate/refreshDRPopsWrapper•987: %03i \n",nForCount);

}
```

If you wish to export the nForCount you can try

```
int exportedValue = 0
int vlFilesOriginal = 100;

    for (int nForCount = 0; nForCount < vlFilesOriginal; nForCount++) {

        printf("AppDelegate/refreshDRPopsWrapper•987: %03i \n",nForCount);
        exportedValue = nForCount
    }
```

Comment: This is what I had at first. I then switched and initialized outside the loop. I´ve done many for loops so far and haven´t had any problems, why now? I don´t understand that. And it´s still not working.

Comment: I changed the type to NSUInteger, now it´s incrementing.